# A New Twist on an Old Cipher

Tags: riddle, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

Presenting a modern cipher —
Like many new cars, and unlike Vigenére, it is keyless.
No quaint, old-timey little Dancing Men or Pigpen symbols.
Nothing so convoluted as PlayFair or Enigma.
No, it's something simple but novel, like a more progressive Caesar.
I'm confident you'll be able to figure it out!

> At ca pqy aqw eohduob kdg xs
>   Rsxmgi mtb ymnx "hnumjw" ltjx
>   Xjjrx ny'x ynrj kux se tkdz ingrrktml —
>   Dpss fvb zapss il vu fvby avlz?
>
> Lupnthapj wbggslz jhu il
>   Ylhssf mbu... Dpss fvb ahrl svun, av
>   Mpuk aom Icbpwz wn ug Abwzg?
>   Wz bpm Aqwpna xo vh Bxwp?
>
> Dbn cqn ludnb cqrb aqhvn prenb cx hxd,
>   Wx wnnm cx secd dkup l rfpdd
>   Opqtytepwk ruzp ftq axpqef
>   Uf'e ftq azq U yhfg fhttrfg!
>
> Asjsf hvwby hvwg fvmas wg igszsgg
>   Zwbs pm zwbs wh wg mcjg vjxst
>   Xih bpe ev uglzmrcvetzvj
>   Efn r jvtiwl oadd mfzavw!
>
> Wfvdwkl tl t yetpexll vbkvex?
>   Xgwexll tl mby Oidqanoa?
>   Eo pda wjosbo vlr'sb burpyarcb
>   Emgle rm msrjgtc rfgq tcpqc?
>
> Fmnc wnt mnv jmnv vgzs lx mzld hr —
>   Sgdqd hr fnhmf sn ad z pthy!

Oh, you'll need this:

> 1 11 19 1 21 17   1 13 1   3 14 16 2  18 2 16

Your final answer is a person's name.
**Who is it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mike Limburg and Techidiout have already found out how to decode the message:

> The message is a Caesar cipher whose shift varies. It starts with a shift of zero. When the encoded letter corresponds to the shift – where A corresponds to 0, B to 1, C to 2 and Z to 25 — the shift increases. (That's why the last letters in stretches of material that was decoded with the same shift end with all the letters of the alphabet in order.)
>
>  Here's the decoded poem with line numbers. The changes of Caesar shift are indicated with vertical bars:
>
>     1   **A** |s **b** |y now you **c** |learly ha**d** | to
>     2   Notic**e** | how this "cipher" goes
>     3   Seems it's time **f** |or my next challen**g** |e -
>     4   Will you still be on your toes?
>
>     5   Enigmatic puzzles can be
>     6   Really fun... Will you take long, to
>     7   Find t**h** |e Author of my Story?
>     8   Or the S**i** |nger of my Song?
>
>     9   Use the clues this rhyme gives to you,
>    10   No need to **j** |ust ta**k** |e a guess
>    11   Definite**l** |y find the oldest
>    12   It's the one I **m** |ust suggest!
>
>    13   **N** |ever think this rhyme is useless
>    14   Line by line it is y**o** |ur guide
>    15   Its ma**p** | of e**q** |uivalencies
>    16   Now a sec**r** |et will unhide!
>
>    17   Endle**s** |s as a flawless circle?
>    18   Endless as **t** |he **U** |ni**v** |erse?
>    19   Is the ans**w** |er you've e**x** |tracted
>    20   Going to outlive this verse?
>
>    21   Hope **y** |ou now know what my name is -
>    22   There is going to be a qui**z** |!

Now we must decode the list of numbers with a cipher hidden in the poem.

> The poem says that the rhyme will be our guide "line for line". It associates lines of the poem with the last letters before the change of the shift. A line can have no, one or several letters associated. For example, 1 may refer to **a**,**b**,**c** or **d**; 2 uniquely refers to **e**; 4 doesn't refer to anything. (This skew relationship makes it impossible to use cryptogram solvers.)
>
>  Applying this to the numbers
>
>     1 11 19 1 21 17   1 13 1   3 14 16 2 18 2 16
>
>  yields:
>
>     abcd·l·wx·abcd·y·s   abcd·n·abcd   fg·o·r·e·tuv·e·r
>
>  and, after selecting the appropriate letters from the lines with multiple options:
>
>    *Always And Forever*

Another thing Mike and Techidiot have found out is ...

> ... that the first letters of each line in the decoded poem read:
>
>     *Answer found in line eight!*
>
>  Line 8 of the poem is:
>
>     *Or the Singer of my Song?*
>
>  There are others songs, music albums and films with the title *Always and forever*, but the poem says that we need the "oldest".

So the final answer may be:

> [**Johnnie Wilder Jr.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnnie_Wilder_Jr.), who was the lead singer of the band [Heatwave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heatwave_(band)), when the song [*Always and Forever*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Always_and_Forever_(Heatwave_song)) was first recorded for their album [*Too Hot to Handle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Too_Hot_to_Handle_(Heatwave_album)) in 1976.

Comment: "... like a more progressive Caesar."  I see what I did there!

Answer (score 5):

[Very Partial]

We can translate the whole text using different ROT-X's.
Starting at ROT26 (normal text) from the top of the text:

> Rot26: **A**
>  Rot25: **s b**
>  Rot24: **y now you c**
>  Rot23: **learly had**
>  Rot22: **to notice**
>  Rot21: **how this "cipher" goes Seems it's time f**
>  Rot20: **or my next challeng**
>  Rot19: **e —Will you still be on your toes? Enigmatic puzzles can be Really fun... Will you take long, to Find th**
>  Rot18: **e Author of my Story? Or the Si**
>  Rot17: **nger of my Song? Use the clues this rhyme gives to you, No need to j**
>  Rot16: **ust tak**
>  Rot15: **e a guess Definitel**
>  Rot14: **y find the oldest It's the one I m**
>  Rot13: **ust suggest! N**
>  Rot12: **ever think this rhyme is useless Line by line it is yo**
>  Rot11: **ur guide Its map**
>  Rot10: **of eq**
>  Rot09: **uivalencies Now a secr**
>  Rot08: **et will unhide! Endles**
>  Rot07: **s as a flawless circle? Endless as t**
>  Rot06: **he U**
>  Rot05: **niv**
>  Rot04: **erse? Is the answ**
>  Rot03: **er you've ex**
>  Rot02: **tracted Going to outlive this verse? Hope y**
>  Rot01: **ou now know what my name is — There is going to be a quiz!**

Final story is:

> As by now you clearly had to
>  notice how this "cipher" goes
>  Seems it's time for my next challenge —
>  Will you still be on your toes?
>  Enigmatic puzzles can be
>  Really fun... Will you take long, to
>  Find the Author of my Story?
>  Or the Singer of my Song?
>  Use the clues this rhyme gives to you,
>  No need to just take a guess
>  Definitely find the oldest
>  It's the one I must suggest!
>  Never think this rhyme is useless
>  Line by line it is your guide
>  Its map of equivalencies
>  Now a secret will unhide!
>  Endless as a flawless circle?
>  Endless as the Universe?
>  Is the answer you've extracted
>  going to outlive this verse?
>  Hope you now know what my name is —
>  There is going to be a quiz!

As @TechIdiot found out, the first characters spell out:

> Answer found in line eight, which is;
>  Or the Singer of my Song?

And, as @Totumus Maximus discovered:

> All ROT-X's endings are the characters of the alphabet, in chrononogical order.

Are we looking for a singer's name, particular who song "My Song?" Then the answer will be:

> [Alessia Cara](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YI4mvJrX1FE)

However, we don't use the numbers there.
I tried playing, converting the numbers into letters from the alphabet and the first letters from line 8, ending emptyhanded.

Comment: Go rot-1....rot-n starting at the bottom to up.

Comment: The "Gnod x" can be rotated one further to give "Hope y".

Comment: <pedantic>When *decrypting* ROT-1, you *subtract* one, making it the same as *encrypting* with ROT-25.</pedantic>

Comment: It's a loooong text :(

Comment: @Techidiot heh, you beat me in a minute! What's next... hm...

Comment: Your current answer basically ignores the numbers.  Not the correct answer, sorry.

Comment: Thought so. The numbers can be interpreted in many ways, still figuring out which way...

Answer (score 5):

Here's the final rhyme -

> Just keep doing rot-n(1,2,3...) starting from bottom to top and forming the rhyme...
>
>
>
>     As by now you clearly had to
>     Notice how this "cipher" goes
>     Seems it's time for my next challenge —
>     Will you still be on your toes?
>
>     Enigmatic puzzles can be
>     Really fun... Will you take long, to
>     Find the Author of my Story?
>     Or the Singer of my Song?
>
>     Use the clues this rhyme gives to you,
>     No need to just take a guess
>     Definitely find the oldest
>     It's the one I must suggest!
>
>     Never think this rhyme is useless
>     Line by line it is your guide
>     Its map of equivalencies
>     Now a secret will unhide!
>
>     Endless as a flawless circle?
>     Endless as the Universe?
>     Is the answer you've extracted
>     Going to outlive this verse?
>
>     Hope you now know what my name is —
>     There is going to be a quiz!
>
>
>  The first letters of the rhyme say - 
>
>  **ANSWER FOUND IN LINE EIGHT**!
>
>  *Or the Singer of my Song?* is the 8th line here -
>
>  Utilizing the numbers and using them as index to this line doesn't lead to anything meaningful yet. May be they are again rot-n indexes...